# Service in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

please tell me that as we have a service in android which can run in background from boot time, which class or interface is available like this in Blackberry.
Actually the app which i made for android i also want to make for the BlackBerry... So please tell me which classes i need for the blackberry so that every time i can get speed value..
thanks, Rachana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you don't want UI interface for your application, Create a BlackBerry application project.
2. If you want to start your application at boot time, go to projects->properties and check 'run on startup'
3. if you donn't want to show application icon of your application, go to projects->properties and check 'System module'